# Regex replace word while keeping capitalisation

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to replace a word. For instance, I want to replace the word "Dog" with "Cat". But I don't want to replace dogmatic or robodog.

I'm using this now:

```
<?php 
$str = preg_replace("/dog\W/", "cat", $str);
?>
```

But I have multiple problems with it. For one, if I use "i" to note I don't care about capitalisation, the replacement string doesn't use the same capitalisation. 
Furthermore, "the dog eats" becomes "the cateats" (without the space).

Can anyone help me with a reliable solution to replace words, including the following cases:
    "dog" -> "cat"
    "a dog, a sheep" -> "a cat, a sheep"
    "My dog" -> "My cat"
And Dog becoming Cat, etc

Comment: The real find/replace pairs are also of equal length. But to generalise the problem, it might be good to go for a general solution, not taking into account the length. In the case the replace is shorter or longer than the find, I would like only the first letter of the replace to take on the capitalisation of the find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create two regular expressions and pass them as an array to `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace(array("/\bdog\b/", "/\bDog\b/"), array("cat", "Cat"), "Dog eats dog");
```

Returns:

```
"Cat eats cat"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use preg_replace_callback

With a regex alone that's probably not possible, you can however use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback).

For the sake of illusration consider the following find and replace paris:

```
$pairs = array(
    'dog' => 'cat',
    'sheep' => 'goat'
);
```

With the following test strings:

```
$tests = array(
    'a dog',
    'Dog darn good',
    'a dog, a sheep',
    'My DOG'
);
```

#### Define an appropriate regex

To match only whole words, use word boundary markers:

```
\bdog\b
```

This will match "dog" but not "dogbert" or "wardog" etc.

If there are multiple words to match for - don't use regexes in a loop, use one regex with alternatives. This code:

```
$pattern = '/\b' . implode('|', array_keys($pairs)) . '\b/i';
```

Will produce this regex:

```
/\bdog|sheep\b/i
```

Which suites the purpose.

#### Use an appropriate callback function

The callback needs to return the replacement for the given match. Here's an example callback:

```
$callback = function($matches) use ($pairs) {
    $match = $matches[0];
    $lc = strtolower($match);
    $replace = $pairs[$lc];

    $chars = str_split($match);

    foreach($chars as $i => $char) {
        if (ctype_upper($char) && isset($replace[$i])) {
            $replace[$i] = strtoupper($replace[$i]);
        }
    }

    return $replace;
};
```

This will make the match lower case to find it in the `$pairs` array and then loop on all characters in the match, and change the case only for upper case characters in the replacement.

#### Putting it to use

With the following test code:

```
foreach($tests as $test) {
    echo "\n> $test\n";
    $test = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $test);
    echo "  $test";
}
```

The results are:

```
> a dog
  a cat
> Dog darn good
  Cat darn good
> a dog, a sheep
  a cat, a goat
> My DOG
  My CAT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$pattern = '/(\\s)*Dog(\\s)*/';
echo $string = 'a Dog, a sheep, or Dog';
echo "<br>";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo "<br>";
echo preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern, 
    function($match) {
        //print_r($match);
        return str_replace('Dog', 'Cat', $match[0]);
    },
    $string);
```